# EF mapping with given type hierarchy proving to be difficult

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

Originally we used TPT mapping for a pretty simple/common hierarchy like this:

- AbstractDestination
- AbstractDestination: Destination1
- AbstractDestination: Destination2

Which mapped to tables:

- AbstractDestination
- Destination1 *(PK is FK to AbstractDestination table)*
- Destination2 *(PK is FK to AbstractDestination table)*

Now we needed to introduce an intermediate class to add some common but new functionality, but still maintain our existing concrete classes.  Our hierarchy now looks something like this:

- AbstractDestination   *(abstract only)*
- AbstractDestination: Destination1
- AbstractDestination: Destination2
- AbstractDestination: IntermediateDestination *(abstract only)*
- AbstractDestination: IntermediateDestination: Destination1
- AbstractDestination: IntermediateDestination: Destination2

Obviously, in c#, we cannot have a Destinaion1 (or 2) class that conditionally inherits from AbstractDestination or IntermediateDestination so we actually end up with:

- AbstractDestination   *(abstract only)*
- AbstractDestination: Destination1
- AbstractDestination: Destination2
- AbstractDestination: IntermediateDestination *(abstract only)*
- AbstractDestination: IntermediateDestination: Destination3
- AbstractDestination: IntermediateDestination: Destination4

So in the end we now have 4 concrete classes (or 4 "Destinations") where Destination3 shares all the same properties as Destination1 and Destination4 shares all the same properties as Destination2.

Since the concrete destinations share the same properties, our DBA wants to re-use the existing tables as much as possible and wants the table structure to look like this (which does make sense to me):

- AbstractDestination
- IntermediateDestination *(PK is FK to AbstractDestination table)*
- Destination1 *(PK is FK to AbstractDestination table)*
- Destination2 *(PK is FK to AbstractDestination table)*

Where essentially the PK is shared across all the tables. For our concrete classes Destination1,Destinatino2 there will be an entry in just the AbstractDestination table and corresponding DestinatinoX table. For our concrete classes Destination3,Destinatino4 there will be an entry in each table.

I have not found a way to map this table structure back into 4 separate concrete classes using EF.

(I prefer code-first fluent API but any mapping strategy is fine)

A possible implementation of this would look something like:

```
public abstract class AbstractDestination
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public partial class Destination1 : AbstractDestination
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public partial class Destination2 : AbstractDestination
{
    public string File { get; set; }
}

public abstract class IntermediateDestination : AbstractDestination
{
    public bool Zip { get; set; } //several new persisted properties
    public string ZipKey { get; set; }
}

public partial class Destination3 : IntermediateDestination        
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; } //same as Destination1
}

public partial class Destination4 : IntermediateDestination
{
    public string File { get; set; } //same as Destination2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if now I've understood but why don't you use the multiple inheritance of interfaces for properties like this?

```
public interface IBlock1 { 
   String Email{ get; set; } 
   Int Guid{ get; set; } 
}

public interface IBlock2 { 
   String Name{ get; set; } 
   Int Number{ get; set; } 
}
```

and then use it as you need in this way

```
public partial class Destination4 : IBlock1 ,IBlock2 
{

}
```

**old answer**

I can suggest you to refer to [**Decorator Design pattern**](http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern) that allow you to add extra functionalities to existing classes

Using it you can maintain your 3 classes

1. AbstractDestination
2. Destination1 (PK is FK to AbstractDestination table)
3. Destination2 (PK is FK to AbstractDestination table)

The classes could be similar to this

```
abstract class AbstractDestination 
{
  public abstract void Operation();
}
```

Concrete class

```
class ConcreteAbstractDestination : AbstractDestination 
{
  public override void Operation()
  {
     Console.WriteLine("ConcreteComponent.Operation()");
  }
}
```

the Decorator Abstract class that implements `AbstractDestination`

```
abstract class Decorator : AbstractDestination
{
  protected AbstractDestination abstractDestination;

  public void SetDestination(AbstractDestination abstractDestination)
  {
    this.abstractDestination= abstractDestination;
  }

  public override void Operation()
  {
     if (abstractDestination != null)
     {
       abstractDestination.Operation();
     }
  }
}
```

At this point you can add your 2 subClasses `Destination1` and `Destination2` with specific behaviors int his way

```
class Destination1: Decorator
{
  public override void Operation()
  {
    base.Operation();
    Console.WriteLine("ConcreteDecoratorA.Operation()");
  }

  void NewBehavior()
  {
    //this is a new behavior
  }
}
```

and

```
class Destination2: Decorator
{
  public override void Operation()
  {
    base.Operation();
    AddedBehavior();
    Console.WriteLine("ConcreteDecoratorB.Operation()");
  }

  void AddedBehavior()
  {
  }

}
```

In Decorator class you can store new shared behaviors between `Destination1` and `Destination2` but you are free to add specific functionality to each class.

In this way you maybe can maintain the same DataBase structure.

Comment: I did briefly explore the Decorator (being a big fan of design patterns); however, my understanding is that it does what you outline above which is for adding new behaviors which isn't what I need...I am actually talking persistence - so the adding of new properties. I will edit the post and see if I can make it more clear.

Comment: @jigamiller I'm sorry for the previous answer, I didn't understand what you needed, I don't know if now my answer can help you